# Formatting in node-xlsx module

Tags: node.js, excel, xlsx

I'm using node-xlsx module to build a xlsx file.

Till version 0.4 input was given like :

```
[{"value":"Name","bold":true,"formatCode":"General","autoWidth":true},"value":"Age","bold":true,"formatCode":"General","autoWidth":true}]
```

So it was easy to format. 
But since v0.5 , it takes data in Array of Array form like :

```
[["Name","age"],["Ashu","25"]
```

Can't figure out how to apply style in this new format.
NPM : https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-xlsx

Comment: The `node-xlsx` is based on SheetJS, read here how to style cells, https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Comment: @bodi0 : I've seen the link. but some tutorials/examples would be appreciated. I'm using node.js.

Comment: @bodiO Does sheetjs support formatting during write ?

Comment: @bodi : I'm not sure. Couldn't find something. All issues on github just show discussion about how formatting should be done, not how its used.

Comment: This is weird, the documentation is lacking... try to contact the developer